# Permit any file type to be uploaded in Media-Wiki?

Tags: file-upload, mediawiki, mime-types, file-extension

I would like to enable all file uploads in *Media-Wiki* (aside from the ones which are explicitly blacklisted like `.exe`).

#### Environment

I am using a virtual-box Linux turnkey ova appliance (turnkey-mediawiki-16.0-buster-amd64) which comes with 16.0 preinstalled.

#### What I tried 1

I have modified the `LocalSettings.php` in several ways to get it working. I have had success uploading some files.

Problem is I have a file type ([.drawio](https://fileinfo.com/extension/drawio)) which actually contains XML when opened in a text editor. When I upload these I get this error:

```
File extension ".drawio" does not match the detected MIME type of the file (application/xml).
```

I can upload the same file if I change the extension to `.xml`. But I want to force people to change file extensions just to get it to upload.

When they download these files the app looks for this extension and they will have to rename them every time. It will get annoying quickly.

#### What I tried 2

- I set `$wgFileUpload = On`
- I added `drawio` and `xml` both to the list of `$wgFileExtensions`.
- I made sure `application/xml` is an allowed mime-type in $`wgTrustedMediaFormats`.
- I tried disabling mime-type validation by setting both `$wgCheckFileExtensions` and `$wgStrictFileExtensions` to `false`.

#### Context

This is for internal, non-public document wiki so I trust the folks using it and I am comfortable with disabling file extension validation and allowing all file types.

Any other thoughts on what I can try?

Answer (score 1):

My bad. `$wgVerifyMimeType = false` works. I fat-fingered it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of totally **disabling the mime-type verification** (security risk), you could also add the missing mapping for *file-extension* `.drawio` and *mime-type* `application/xml` like described in similar question:

[How to skip MIME type check for .OFT file extensions on MediaWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542781/how-to-skip-mime-type-check-for-oft-file-extensions-on-mediawiki/63690883#63690883)

In your host-environment (Linux, Debian-based like [Media-Wiki Turnkey images](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/updates/new-turnkey-mediawiki-version-160)) you can modify the mime-types rules at [`/etc/mime.types`](https://wiki.debian.org/MIME/etc/mime.types), by adding the required mapping from *mime-type* to *file-extension*:

```
application/xml                drawio
```

and add the path to this **mime-type file** in `LocalSettings.php` like:

```
$wgMimeTypeFile = "/etc/mime.types";
```

Then Media-Wiki will acknowledge the new file-type (mime-type matching file-extension) when verifying the received file and finally allow the upload.

Comment: There is also a Media-Wiki [Extension:DrawioEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DrawioEditor) to allows inline editing of Draw.io diagrams.